# Use Paper Trail in Rails 6.0.0.beta1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, paper-trail-gem, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to upgrade my rails application from 5.2.2 to version 6.0.0.beta1. Ruby version currently using is ruby-2.5.3. But it gives me dependencies issues related to already added gems. Likewise in case of paper_trail. I have tried by forking paper_trail gem, comment out the dependencies inside gemspec files and provide a reference to that forked application to application. It removes dependencies but still doesn't work for me. Any idea on how to use this gem in rails 6.0.0beta1 version?

Steps to upgrade rails version in my application:

1. Changed gem 'rails', '~>5.2.2' to gem 'rails', '6.0.0.beta1', github: 'rails/rails', ref: '5a0230c67f852fb21173f99647e76336897446c1'
2. Run 'bundle update rails'

And it produced issues as below.

```
    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    annotate was resolved to 2.7.4, which depends on
      activerecord (< 6.0, >= 3.2)

    delayed_job_active_record was resolved to 4.1.3, which depends on
      activerecord (< 5.3, >= 3.0)

    kaminari was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.1.1) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
        activerecord

    paper_trail was resolved to 10.2.0, which depends on
      activerecord (< 6.1, >= 4.2)

    rails (= 6.0.0.beta1) was resolved to 6.0.0.beta1, which depends on
      activerecord (= 6.0.0.beta1)

    rails-erd was resolved to 1.5.2, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.2)

    activeadmin-select2 was resolved to 0.1.8, which depends on
      activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
        ransack (>= 1.8.7) was resolved to 2.1.1, which depends on
          activerecord (>= 5.0)

    seed_dump was resolved to 3.3.1, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4)

    state_machines-activerecord was resolved to 0.5.2, which depends on
      activerecord (< 6.0, >= 4.1)

    textacular was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
      activerecord (< 6.0, >= 5.0)
```

Comment: When you look closely at the list you will notice that `papertrail` is not the only issue. `delayed_job_active_record`, `state_machines-activerecord` and `textacular` aren't ready for Ruby on Rails 6.0 yet too. You basically have only two options: 1) Wait for new releases of all the gems and hope that they will support Rails 6.0 then. Or 2) fork all that gems, figure out why thex do not support Rails 6.0 and fix them yourself.  I suggest waiting. It is just unreasonable to expect open source maintainers to support a Rails version that is not even released yet.

Comment: Yes I know that there are other issues like you pointed out some. I just gave one of them example so I could find out a way to make them work for me. BTW thanks for you help @spickermann